# Instant open piston door with delayed deactivation with pressure plates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I was wondering if anyone knew of a proper way to get a pressure plate to trigger a series of pistons instantly, but have their deactivation delayed by about a variable number of seconds.

I've tried this with a NAND gate and simply adding repeaters but this actually causes the door to open and close rapidly 2-6 times depending on how many repeaters you place.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### A simple pulse lengthener will work here.

[image: Screenshot]

It works like this:

The first block gets powered from the pressure plate (or you can power it in some other way), the redstone line immediately takes power from there, so all the pistons go up instantly. After some time the repeater draws power from the block and powers the next block, and so on...

When you step off the pressure plate, the first block no longer powers the redstone line, but all the next blocks still do; the first repeater turns off after some time and the 2nd block is not powered anymore... but the line is powered until the last block loses power.

If the signal is shorter than 4 ticks, this scheme won't work well, but buttons always give a 5-tick pulse and pressure plates' signal lasts at least 5 ticks.

And by the way, I used iron blocks, but these can be any non-transparent blocks,

---

#### Old answer

Or, for a different behavior, use an [RS NOR Latch](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits#RS_NOR_Latch_.26_Input-Stabilizers) as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prjan.png).
This scheme will keep the pistons up for at least the time it takes the current to go through the repeaters, or for more time if the player keeps standing on the pressure plate.

Comment: If I may ask is it possible to extend the length of the deactivation using this method?

Comment: @CaseyWeed Of course, just add more repeaters

Comment: Perfect, will have to try it then.

Comment: How will this behave if you do not step off the pressure plate?  It was my understanding that the desired outcome was to only have the delayed deactivation when the player steps off the pressure plate.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yes, I've added the information. If it's not the desired behavior, I think I can change it.

Comment: If there is any problem with the amount of time the player stands on the plate, I will probably just switch it out for a button. That might be a better option anyhow.

Comment: @CaseyWeed the button would work the same way.

Comment: But wouldn't the button's more constant activation/deactivation speed inhibit the behavior that is present with the pressure plates?

Comment: @CaseyWeed No, this will deactivate the pistons as soon as the button deactivates.

Comment: Well damn. That's unfortunate.

Comment: @CaseyWeed While I was thinking of ways to improve on *OrigamiRobot*'s answer, I remembered [this video](http://youtu.be/rUg5J01ZqBI) and realized that a pulse lengthener is just perfect here. See the updated answer.

Comment: Your new solution, the pulse lengthener, seems to be the ideal solution. It instantly activates, then deactivates after a short period of time. What's great is it's easy to build and adding a longer line of repeaters doesn't seem to cause any funny behavior.

Comment: I was skeptical of this at first, then tested it.  Works as advertised.  The crux is that the iron blocks power the redstone, but the redstone can't power the iron blocks, preventing it from latching.

Comment: I tried this with wooden blocks and it also works great.

Comment: The blocks do not matter as far as I am aware. I have only just recently started to play again since... I think Beta 1.7 so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a line of repeaters in parallel with a straight redstone wire and adjust the repeaters to give you the desired off delay.
[image]

The only catch is you have to let the repeaters "charge up" to get the off delay to work.  Otherwise, the piston will turn off, the turn on, then have a delayed off.

Comment: A fix for the catch: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dzd1Z.png :D

Comment: @BlaXpirit - I don't see how that fixes it.

Comment: It won't "turn off, then turn on, then have a delayed off". Note that all the repeaters have the same direction.

Comment: @BlaXpirit I didn't notice the repeaters have different delays.  I had considered this, but to make it work best, you'd need a cascade of 1-tick delays.  I didn't mention it because it is impractically large.

Comment: I've tried this and it seems like it just might be my best bet. It has a good enough delay and even if it might be large when scaled up, at least it works reliably and is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

One way to delay the deactivation of a signal is to add a parallel path of activation that contains repeaters to create the delay **AND** has a long enough length of redstone wire on the end (i.e. greater than 15 blocks) such that it can't reactivate itself. Here's an example:

```
^*******
 *     *
 *     *
 PR*****

P = pressure plate
R = repeater
* = redstone wire
^ = piston
```

Comment: I think my friend actually came up with this by happenchance and it worked, but it was very large to build up a delay long enough for you to walk through. I'll have to try this and modify it.